# Are order of magnitude approximation questions on-topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

Are order of magnitude approximation questions on-topic?

e.g. How long (order of magnitude) did it take for Pluto to form to 90% of its size?

This seems like an on-topic Astrophysics problem, but will likely result in a number of different answers. The only way to determine which answer is the best would be by upvoting.

Is this an appropriate question for Astronomy Stack Exchange?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, for answers in which a order of magnitude estimation is the best available, then that should be the answer. It should perhaps be left to the answerer of a question what is an appropriate level of accuracy, though I see nothing wrong with questioners indicating that a "Fermi estimate" is sufficient for them.

That "the only way to decide which answer is best is by upvoting" seems to be no problem at all, indeed, that is the principle paradigm of the site.

Comment: Not just here, but in all Science SE's, 'cept Math.